# What do Peter's words mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Peter is talking about his old man, who is being taken care of under Kate.

> Peter: The docs **figure a month maybe. He's pretty far gone**.
>
> Kate: I understand.
>
> Peter: His wife's having kind of a rough time with it.

Is Peter saying that "a month" is the time left before the old man's death, or that the old man survived more than one month and is still surviving?
Or does it mean anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paraphrase:

> The doctors calculate [that] perhaps a month [remains]. He has travelled a long distance [toward his destination].

As you surmise, the destination the old man is approaching is his death.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are right. The meaning of the sentence is that according to the doctors, the person has about one month left to live.

Comment: "Docs" is probably short for "doctors" rather than "documents" in this context. But otherwise, yes.

Comment: Valid point. Being a Computer Scientist, I always think of documents first. :P